# Equivalent of api for test dependency in gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I'm having multi module gradle project. In one of my modules I'm having api dependency:

```
api('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')
```

I want to change it to dependency that will be visible in tests, across all modules. There is a `testImplementation` dependency but there is no `testApi`.

I cannot have this dependency on production classpath anymore since I want to use real mongo instance instead of embedded one. On the other hand I have tests in different modules that depend on data access - in that case I want to run those test with embedded mongo on test classpath.

How I can make this dependency visible in all modules tests?

Answer (score 4):

The question (appears to me) is sharing the test code across modules in a multi-module project

Short answer - No - there is direct test dependency share across modules.

To share test code between modules internally via build settings

**Official gradle route** https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:java_test_fixtures

**Simple hack**

```
testImplementation files(project(':core-module').sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs)
```

add the above line either individually where you need or in root with `subprojects()` with appropriate condition

*there are other possible routes as well *
ex: via configuration
`child.testImplementation extends parent.testImplementation (or runtime)`

Comment: is it different about testImplementation ":core-module" ?

Answer (score -2):

[image: gradle tasks]

`testCompileClassPath` includes `api` dependencies so you are all good here, `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` will be visible in your tests.

Comment: > Could not find method testCompileClassPath() for arguments [de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: No that's not the way it works. Just keep `api('de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo')` and `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` will be visible in your tests

Comment: But I don't want to have it in compiled production files :)

Comment: You don't want to have it as an `api` dependency anymore ? I am not sure to understand...

Comment: I want to have equivalent of `api` dependency but for tests - I cannot use `api` because I don't want to have this dependency on production classpath anymore

Comment: `testApi` would be a nonsense as by design, tests are not meant to be exposed. So just use `testImplementation` i guess, `de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo` won't be on production classpath anymore.

Comment: I'm having a module `data-layer` and for me - it would make sense to spread such dependency across all tests

Comment: Sorry i am not getting the whole picture here, please edit the question with more details.