# Equivalent of api for test dependency in gradle

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

This question has been posted already [Equivalent of api for test dependency in gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52440967/equivalent-of-api-for-test-dependency-in-gradle) but I don't see any solution.

we have few dependencies declared as below

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.apache.curator:curator-test:4.2.0'
    testImplementation 'org.apache.curator:curator-framework:4.2.0'
}
```

We want to expose these to consumers of this library. Since it's testImplementation, consumers need to explicitly declare these dependencies which we want to avoid.

So I am looking to change **testImplementation** to its api equivalent. But I don't find any in documentation https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_configurations_graph

Comment: Why would you want to expose test dependencies to consumers of your library? What is the actual use case?

Answer (score 0):

> So I am looking to change **testImplementation** to its api equivalent. But I don't find any in documentation

There is no equivalent and test dependencies should be separate from the main library module. You would create a separate published library that is specifically for tests. This is exactly what Spring projects do.

For example, the test library for Spring Boot has all the necessary test dependencies as `api`: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-test/build.gradle